# Rails - Devise - Where is the sign in .html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I was just going to style the sign in page, as I had done the edit and sign up pages, but for the life of me I cannot find the file to edit.

So where can I find "users/sign_in"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `$ rails generate devise:views`,  this copies the devise views to your project.

The sign in view will then be located at `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

More info: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views

Comment: I have looked there.  I used the rails composer app to generate this application, since it nicely put all my configuration items together for me.  https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/

I see the registration views, just not the session ones.

Comment: I see, I have to override them to create actual views.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate it by using the command `rails generate devise:views`. You can see more details in devise's [documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).